# Eclipse maven suddenly looking into C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository rather my USERPROFILE directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

My eclipse maven build was working fine for long time and suddenly it started throwing following error. I looked at the my profile directory (C:\Users\amahe6.m2) and settings.xml isnt there but I guess it wasnt there earlier as well. I am using eclipse Luna (4.4.2).

> [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on. [DEBUG] Reading global
>   settings from EMBEDDED\conf\settings.xml [DEBUG] Reading user settings
>   from C:\Users\Administrator.m2\settings.xml [DEBUG] Using local
>   repository at C:\Users\Administrator.m2\repository [ERROR] Could not
>   create local repository at C:\Users\Administrator.m2\repository ->
>   [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.repository.LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException:
>   Could not create local repository at
>   C:\Users\Administrator.m2\repository     at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.validateLocalRepository(DefaultMaven.java:578)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:221)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

My eclipse settings are as follows - 
[image]

M2_repo class variable also points to the correct directory-
[image]

What is gone wrong suddenly ? Any pointers will be helpful...

Comment: can you check the maven_home is pointing to which dir?

Comment: @AmitK maven_home is pointing to where maven 3 is installed but I guess eclipse uses its embedded version , I am using m2e plugin.

Comment: you can try givng your maven installation path, or try running maven command from command line.